# How to prevent jquery dot evaluation when there are no matching elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

> $('#someElement').somePlugin(someArgs);

The above jquery statement produces the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'somePlugin'

I know that somePlugin does not exist in this context, but it shouldn't matter because #someElement also does not exist.

What's the best way to prevent the right side of the dot from evaluating when there are no matching elements?

Comment: `if ($('#someElement').length) { $('#someElement').somePlugin(someArgs); }`. You cannot prevent the method from being called when the set is empty, because that's just how JavaScript works. JavaScript doesn't know what `$` returns and jQuery doesn't know what you are going to do with the (empty) selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways, one is:

```
var element = $('#someElement');
element.somePlugin && element.somePlugin(someArgs);
```

You could also test if the plugin itself is loaded:

```
if ( $.fn.somePlugin ) { 
  // stuff...
}
```

Comment: Aaah, the performance horror! Please use `var element = $("#someElement"); element.somePlugin && element.somePlugin(someArgs);`

Comment: Indeed! Edited the answer

Comment: Thanks man! It's always good to proliferate these simple things.

Comment: I like `if ( $.fn.somePlugin ) {...}` because the intent is clearly and concisely conveyed.